# Can a statically typed language support metaclasses like smalltalk/python/ruby?

Tags: metaclass, static-typing

I find the concept of metaclass fascinating, it treats classes as first class objects. You can assign a class to a variable, pass it to a method, and even create new classes at runtime. It seems that, every programming language that supports metaclasses are either dynamic typed languages(Smalltalk, Python, Ruby) or gradually typed languages(Objective C and Groovy both support static and dynamic typing). I have not seen a statically typed language that supports metaclasses.

Are static typing and metaclasses incompatible with each other? It does seem to me that, metaclass' functionalities require a certain degree of dynamism. I still wonder if it is technically possible for a static typed language like Java, C# and Kotlin to support metaclass and have classes as first class objects, or is it theoretically impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that Python itself is implemented in C, and its objects can be "seen" and used in C through its API, the answer is "yes".

What may be harder in some languages is that objects belonging to a class hyerarchy were they have proper metaclasses, introspection, and runtime class creation may be a little tougher - requiring the code that implements such metaclasses to replicate part of the language runtime itself, or to call, at runtime, different code generation functions - at very least, one class could generate the source code with the declaration for the dynamically created classes, and iterate with the runtime to compile and load that code into the current process.

With C++, for example, where one can have full control of in-memory layout of data, maybe it is possible to emulate compiled classes with a lighter approach, that just fill in data-structures and redo the name-mangling part to attach class members.

If that would be something convenient, however, it is another question altogether. Maybe it is just better to leave metaclasses either for languages that support it out of the box, or, for languages were you are implementing a class system from scratch (like the Python runtime does using C).

Comment: It seems that C++23 will have such a feature called 'Metaclass'. Since you mentioned C++ here, how do you think about this? Is it similar to metaclasses in dynamically typed languages such as Smalltalk and Python?